# Desktop theme changed, settings too

Tags: 13.04

I opened Ubuntu today and see that the template is changed of the desktop, my settings too, launcher icons too. Why? What happened? On the login page, the desktop theme is as before. Please help me.

**edit:** It even doesn't allow me to change the settings. When I turn on auto-hide launcher, it just go back to OFF in 100 milliseconds. Can't change desktop theme, can't change language etc.

When I open terminal:
bash: /usr/local/etc/bash_profiles/source-profiles-bash: No such file or directory
SourceMyDotFile: command not found

It affects just one user, when I use guest account or created a new one, it works fine. I need to fix the user I think.

Comment: Did you get a warning of a crash during your previous session? It could be that a crash has resulted in a reset.

Comment: SimplySimon: No. And when I remove the icons in the launcher and login again, it again shows useless icons like Amazon etc.

Comment: it sounds like the config file is either write protected or corrupt. I don't know enough about it to give a full answer, as I hide it away and use Cairo Dock instead.

Comment: @hey Did you try to login as root? Or changed rights in home folder?